# cannot find symbol error while building java code on JDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven, security, x509certificate, pkcs#10

I am building Java code with `JDK 1.8` on `maven` . During the build i am getting `cannot find symbol error` .

error stack trace on maven :

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[6,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[7,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[12,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[67,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[67,36] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[82,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[148,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[150,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[152,31] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[199,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
\myfiles.java:[199,42] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 11 errors
```

I think some of the files are missing in JDK 1.8 .

I am getting errors on these lines of code

```
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10;
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10Attributes;
import sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen;
```

Also getting some warnings too

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[8,24] DerInputStream is internal pro
prietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[9,24] DerOutputStream is internal pr
oprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[10,24] DerValue is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[11,24] AlgorithmId is internal propr
ietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[13,24] CertificateAlgorithmId is int
ernal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[14,24] CertificateIssuerName is inte
rnal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[15,24] CertificateSerialNumber is in
ternal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[16,24] CertificateSubjectName is int
ernal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[17,24] CertificateValidity is intern
al proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[18,24] CertificateVersion is interna
l proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[19,24] CertificateX509Key is interna
l proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[20,24] X500Name is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[21,24] X509CertImpl is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[22,24] X509CertInfo is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[23,24] X509Key is internal proprieta
ry I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[62,8] X500Name is internal proprieta
ry I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[62,31] X500Name is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[94,8] X509CertInfo is internal propr
ietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[95,35] CertificateIssuerName is inte
rnal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[95,61] X500Name is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[96,37] CertificateValidity is intern
al proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[97,41] CertificateSerialNumber is in
ternal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[99,8] AlgorithmId is internal propri
etary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[101,24] AlgorithmId is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[101,36] AlgorithmId is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[103,24] AlgorithmId is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[103,36] AlgorithmId is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[105,40] CertificateAlgorithmId is in
ternal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[107,8] X509CertImpl is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[107,32] X509CertImpl is internal pro
prietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[121,19] X509CertInfo is internal pro
prietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[134,8] DerValue is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[134,32] DerValue is internal proprie
tary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[135,8] DerInputStream is internal pr
oprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[135,32] DerInputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[136,8] DerValue is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[138,8] DerValue is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[138,40] DerInputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[146,8] X500Name is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[146,35] X500Name is internal proprie
tary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[147,41] X509Key is internal propriet
ary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[154,8] AlgorithmId is internal propr
ietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[154,34] AlgorithmId is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[161,8] DerOutputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[161,37] DerOutputStream is internal
proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[162,8] DerOutputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[162,38] DerOutputStream is internal
proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[163,8] DerOutputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[163,34] DerOutputStream is internal
proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[175,8] DerOutputStream is internal p
roprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[175,38] DerOutputStream is internal
proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[177,30] DerValue is internal proprie
tary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[190,8] X509CertInfo is internal prop
rietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[190,32] X509CertInfo is internal pro
prietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[192,32] CertificateVersion is intern
al proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[193,32] CertificateSubjectName is in
ternal proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] 
\myfiles.java:[194,28] CertificateX509Key is intern
al proprietary I and may be removed in a future release
[INFO] 57 warnings
```

I am trying to build these code for Java 8 . So i just want to know these import are correct in JDK 1.8 ? This is working well on JDK 1.6 too . Any dependencies are missing ? Any suggestion please .

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: From the JDK8 compatibility notes: "Some APIs in the sun.* packages have changed. These APIs are not intended for use by developers. Developers importing from sun.* packages do so at their own risk."

Comment: So what are the newest sun.* packages available for  JDK 1.8 ? Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd advise against using those, too. Try to find regular APIs to use instead of ones that you're explicitly discouraged from using. Without knowing what your code is trying to do, it's hard to help you further, but if it's crypto stuff, I'd look in javax.crypto first.

Comment: Do not use such area in JDK...it should be prevented for a very long time...Use something from libs /etc other implementations...

Comment: Can i suppress these warnings/errors with compiler flags in Java C  ?